Styles in styled components not automatically applied in my app
I'm using Vite for my app and Styled Components for styling. I'm encountering a problem every time I run 'npm run dev' or refresh the browser that is the styles in my app won't automatically apply. They only apply when I resave the file containing the declaration of the styled component. Here is a sample of the styled component:
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Input = styled.input`
  ${(props) =>
    props.mode === "regular" &&
    css`
      max-width: fit-content;
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.mode === "long" &&
    css`
      max-width: 100%;
    `}

    ${(props) =>
    props.mode === "short" &&
    css`
      max-width: 50%;
    `}

  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 0.6rem 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;

  &:invalid {
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
`;

Input.defaultProps = {
  mode: "regular",
};

export default Input;


Below is the vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})


Any help would be appreciated, It's really annoying to go to the file and press save to see the styles applied in my app.
I tried looking for answers across the internet but haven't found anything that is of use
